# PHP using number_format and displaying the decimal point correctly

Tags: php, number-formatting

My number is 495 plain and simple.

I'm trying to format this number to have it display $4.95

what I've done is `number_format($number, 2, '.', '')`

but that outputs `495.00`

I know it can't be this difficult. Anyone familiar with `number_format`?

I just need it to add a decimal two numbers from the right so the cents are always displayed. ex. 4.95, 12.58, 23.39... You get the idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Read the question wrong, if I could delete this I would!

Comment: Also, you should note the last two parameters in that instance are cruft (those are the defaults)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with integers instead of floats, you'd first have to divide by 100.

```
$number = 495;
echo number_format($number/100, 2, '.', '')
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! I can't believe it. My brain is done today. Thanks jboneca

Comment: @ValleyDigital sure thing, bud!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are all whole numbers you can do the following:

```
$mynum = 495;

function formatMyNum($num) {
    return $num/100;
}
```

Comment: Why writing function for everything when you just can divide $number by 100?

Comment: I assume you would want to reuse the logic. Personal preference I guess. A developer coming after you many not know why you are dividing by 100 so a function can be self documentation

Answer (score 0):

Number format just displays `floats` using N number of decimals and the decimal/thousand separator characters you choose.

If you passed `4.95` to it, it would show fine so to do that just divide your `$number` by `100` before passing it to the function.

```
echo number_format($number/100, 2, '.', '');
```